# Opening a fragment inside a fragment in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, barcode-scanner

I have a frame layout. In which I have set a scanner view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:padding="10dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.budiyev.android.codescanner.CodeScannerView
        android:id="@+id/scanner_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:autoFocusButtonColor="@android:color/white"
        app:autoFocusButtonVisible="true"
        app:flashButtonColor="@android:color/white"
        app:flashButtonVisible="true"
        app:frameColor="@android:color/white"
        app:frameCornersSize="50dp"
        app:frameCornersRadius="0dp"
        app:frameAspectRatioWidth="1"
        app:frameAspectRatioHeight="1"
        app:frameSize="0.75"
        app:frameThickness="2dp"
        app:maskColor="#77000000"/>
</FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Right now I am opening it on another fragment but I don't want to do it. I want to open it on a button click

```
 @BindView(R.id.start_scan)
 ImageButton startScan;

public void bindListners()
{
   startScan.setOnClickListener(startScanning);
}

private final View.OnClickListener startScanning = v -> {

     if(v.getId()==R.id.start_scan){
       //here I want to call it
     }

}
```

**Update 1 MainActivity**

I also have some other fragments which are in my `MainActivity`. Below is my whole main activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
//fragments
ScanFragment scanFragment = null;
NewFormFragment mNewFormFragment = null;
InstallationListFragment mInstallationListFragment = null;
ProgressFragment progressFragment = null;
boolean quitPress = false;

NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            Common.hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
        }
    };
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mNewFormFragment = new NewFormFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out, android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mNewFormFragment, Constants.FRAGMENTS_NEW_FORM_TAG)
            .commit();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.new_form);

    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView t = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    t.setText(Common.SharedPreferenceHelper.getSharedPreference(this, getString(R.string.user_name_key), ""));

    Log.d("zaidi","auth = "+Common.getAuthKey(this));

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0 && !quitPress) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Press again to quit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        quitPress = true;
    } else {
        quitPress = false;
        try {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        String backStack = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(manager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
        setNavigationItem(getMenuIdByTag(backStack));
    } else {
        setNavigationItem(getMenuIdByTag(Constants.FRAGMENTS_NEW_FORM_TAG));
    }
}

private void setNavigationItem(int id) {
    try {
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(id).setChecked(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private int getMenuIdByTag(String tag) {
    switch (tag) {
        case Constants.FRAGMENTS_NEW_FORM_TAG: {
            return 0;
        }
        case Constants.FRAGMENT_INSTALLATIONS_TAG: {
            return 1;
        }
        case Constants.FRAGMENT_INSTALLATION_PROGRESS_TAG: {
            return 2;
        }
        case Constants.FRAGMENT_SETTINGS_TAG: {
            return 3;
        }
        default: {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Common.hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        SettingsFragment myFragment = (SettingsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Constants.FRAGMENT_SETTINGS_TAG);
        if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
            // add your code here
        } else {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out, android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment(), Constants.FRAGMENT_SETTINGS_TAG)
                    .addToBackStack(Constants.FRAGMENT_SETTINGS_TAG).commit();
            fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
            setNavigationItem(getMenuIdByTag(Constants.FRAGMENT_SETTINGS_TAG));
        }
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.new_form) {
        NewFormFragment myFragment = (NewFormFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Constants.FRAGMENTS_NEW_FORM_TAG);
        if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible() && this.getTitle() == "New Form") {
            // add your code here

        } else if (mNewFormFragment == null) {
            mNewFormFragment = new NewFormFragment();
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out, android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mNewFormFragment, Constants.FRAGMENTS_NEW_FORM_TAG)
                .addToBackStack(Constants.FRAGMENTS_NEW_FORM_TAG).commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    } else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        SettingsFragment myFragment = (SettingsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Constants.FRAGMENT_SETTINGS_TAG);
        if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
            // add your code here
        } else {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out, android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment(), Constants.FRAGMENT_SETTINGS_TAG)
                    .addToBackStack(Constants.FRAGMENT_SETTINGS_TAG).commit();
            fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        }
    } else if (id == R.id.installations) {
        InstallationListFragment myFragment = (InstallationListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Constants.FRAGMENT_INSTALLATIONS_TAG);
        if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
            // add your code here
        } else {
            if (this.mInstallationListFragment == null) {
                this.mInstallationListFragment = new InstallationListFragment();
            }
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out, android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mInstallationListFragment, Constants.FRAGMENT_INSTALLATIONS_TAG)
                    .addToBackStack(Constants.FRAGMENT_INSTALLATIONS_TAG).commit();
            fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        }
    } else if (id == R.id.progress) {
        ProgressFragment myFragment = (ProgressFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Constants.FRAGMENT_INSTALLATION_PROGRESS_TAG);
        if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
            // add your code here
        } else {
            if (this.progressFragment == null) {
                this.progressFragment = new ProgressFragment();
            }
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out, android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, progressFragment, Constants.FRAGMENT_INSTALLATION_PROGRESS_TAG)
                    .addToBackStack(Constants.FRAGMENT_INSTALLATION_PROGRESS_TAG).commit();
            fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                mNewFormFragment.getGPSLocation();

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        case Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (mNewFormFragment.checkStoragePermission()) {
                    mNewFormFragment.openCamera();
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        case Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_STORAGE_REQUEST_FOR_CAMERA_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the

                mNewFormFragment.openCamera();

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }
        case RefreshRefrenceNumber.WRITE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_REF_NO: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                RefreshRefrenceNumber.refreshManagerInstance(this).refreshReferenceNumber();
                RefreshMeterNumber.refreshManagerInstance(this).refreshMetetNumber();
                RefreshImsiNumber.refreshManagerInstance(this).refreshImsiNumber();
            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: i dont know what you are trying to but for opening fragment into a fragment you should make a framelayout in parent fragment and replace child fragment to it either from any button click..

Comment: I don't want to start any other activity I want to open the `frameLayout` on my parent fragment

Comment: i am not suggesting you to open any other activity just in same activity replace a fragmentA in framelayout and in fragmentA's xml make another framlayout and add fragmentB...

Comment: @MajidAli didn't got it properly

Answer (score 1):

When I have to manage several fragments whose actions in one can launch the other, here is the architecture I use:
A parent activity that manages the launch of fragments, let's call it MainActivity:
and the framents:
Fragment1 and Fragment2: here are the codes:

MainActivity

```
           public class MAinActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements
                 Fragment1.ActionListener,
                 Fragment2.ActionListener {
                 private FragmentManager manager=null;
                
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
                  manager=getSupportFragmentManager();

               //you should launch one fragment at startup
               changefrag(new Fragment1());

       }
       public void changefrag(Fragment frag) {

          manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

         if (!manager.beginTransaction().isEmpty()) {
          manager.beginTransaction().detach(frag);
         }
       manager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.activity_main_frame_layout, frag).commit();

      }



    /**
     *
     *To start Fragment1 when action is perform in Fragment2
     */
    @Override
    public void onFragment1() {
     changefrag(new Fragment1());
    }

     /**
      * to start frament 2 when action is performe inside Fragment1
      * @param id
      */


     @Override
     public void onFragment2() {
        changefrag(new Fragment2());
     }
 }
```

Fragment1:

```
 public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private ActionListener listerner;

   public Fragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

   public static Fragment1 newInstance() {
    Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
 
    return fragment;
    }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   listener=(ActionListener)getActivity();
     
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
      view.findViewById(R.id.start_frag2).setOnClickListener(new 
           View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

            listener.onFragment2();
        }
    });
    return view;
  
    }
     public interface ActionListener{
       void onFragment2();
   
     }
   }
```

Fragment2:

```
 public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    private ActionListener listerner;

   public Fragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

   public static Fragment2 newInstance() {
    Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
 
    return fragment;
    }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   listener=(ActionListener)getActivity();
     
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
      view.findViewById(R.id.start_frag1).setOnClickListener(new 
           View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

            listener.onFragment1();
        }
    });
    return view;
  
    }
     public interface ActionListener{
       void onFragment1();
   
     }
   }
```

Comment: I have added my main activity. Can you please confirm me where I an add it?

Comment: It can be anywhere in your project( i'mnot sure what you ask for). If you already create your meanactivity you just need to let it implements interface inside your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

DO this on button click

```
   Fragment someFragment = new SomeFragment(); 
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, someFragment ); 
// give your fragment container id in first parameter
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);  
// if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: it will open a new fragment in another view